# How to plot multiple lines from CSV data using plotly?

Tags: plotly

I have a CSV file with 3 columns: stock, date, price

I would like to plot it using Plotly.js as multiple lines (1 per stock).

Do I need to unpack each stock to a variable 'manually' or is there a function for doing this? (I've searched the docs and couldn't find anything)

Comment: Can you share some data?

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to arrange the CSV file so that the header row is ['Date','StockA','StockB','StockC']. Then each following row is ['actual_date','PriceA','PriceB','PriceC']. This way, you can run the javascript map function to output to individual traces.

I recently pieced together something like this but cannot find the links to credit at the moment:

```
<div id=chartID></div>
<script>

    Plotly.d3.csv('/chart_data.csv', function(err, rows){
      function unpack(rows, key) {
        return rows.map(function(row) {return row[key]; });
      }

      var trace1 = {
        type: "scatter",
        mode: "lines",
        name: "StockA",
        x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
        y: unpack(rows, 'StockA'),
        line: {
          color: '#FF8700',
          width: 3,
          shape: "spline"
        }
      }

      var trace2 = {
        type: "scatter",
        mode: "lines",
        name: "Stock B",
        x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
        y: unpack(rows, 'StockB'),
        line: {
          color: '#81827F',
          width: 3,
          shape: "spline"
        }
      }

      var trace3 = {
        type: "scatter",
        mode: "lines",
        name: "Stock C",
        x: unpack(rows, 'Date'),
        y: unpack(rows, 'StockC'),
        line: {
          color: '#04824C',
          width: 3,
          shape: "spline"
        }
      }

      var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

      var layout = {
       // Put your visual settings here
        };


      Plotly.newPlot('chartID', data, layout);

    })

</script>
```